# Implicating convex combinations through inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given an inequality e.g. $a<b<c$, why does this implicate that $b$ is a convex combination of $a,c$, meaning that there exist two numbers $x,y \in (0,1):x+y=1 $ so that $b=xa+yc$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intuition:** Geometrically, the convex combinations of two points generate the line segment that connects them. In this case, the convex combinations of $a$ and $c$ generate the interval $[a,c]$, or $(a,c)$ in your question, since your $x,y$ can't be $0$ or $1$. If $a < b < c$, then obviously $b \in (a,c)$.

Now, to actually find the coefficients $x$ and $y$ that make $b$ a convex combination of $a$ and $c$, we can use that geometrical intuition. Starting at $a$, we want to "walk" $b-a$ units in the direction of $c - a$ (the vector that goes from $a$ to $c$). So:

$$b = a + \frac{b-a}{c-a}(c-a) = \left(1 - \frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)a + \frac{b-a}{c-a}c = \frac{c-b}{c-a} a + \frac{b-a}{c-a}c = xa+yc$$

It's easy to see that $x,y \in (0,1)$ and $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(t)=a(1-t)+bt$ is a continuous function, thus by [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem),  it takes on any given value between $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$ at some point within the $(0,1)$.